# Why doesn't a ternary operator with assignment return the expected output?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

I'm wondering why assignment with the ternary operator reacts strangely:

```
a = "foo"­
=> "foo"
a = nil ? nil : a
=> "foo"
a
=> "foo"
```

but:

```
a = nil ? nil : a
=> "foo"
a = "bar"­ ? "bar"­ : a
=> "bar"
a
=> "bar"
```

and:

```
if a = nil
  puts "should be nil"
end
=> nil
```

won't `puts` the string because `a = nil` will return `nil` thus false, although the assignment was successful.

Is that all behaving like intended?

Comment: "the assignment was successful" seems to be the key misconception here. The result of an assignment expression is (and is supposed to be) the assigned value, not whether the assignment "succeeded". (In fact a variable assignment can't really fail.)

Comment: in this example i'm not confusing assignment with the comparison, ok if i assign i get back the value assign confusion cleared about that thx to you all but why is a still "foo" in my first example with the Ternary Operator although i assigned nil ?

Comment: Your first example should be read as `a = (nil ? nil : a)`. Since nil is "*falsey*", you assign the previous value of `a` to `a`, which is `"foo"`.

Comment: so (a = nil) ? nil : a would return my expected value, great thx ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if a = nil
```

This isn't returning false, it's returning what was assigned, which in this case was `nil`. `nil` is 'falsy' so that's why it does not go into the `puts`

As to why:

```
a = "foo"­
=> "foo"
a = nil ? nil : a
=> "foo"
a
=> "foo"
```

It's because you are assigning `a` again. `nil ? nil : a` returns `a` so that's what gets assigned. So `a = nil ? nil: a` ends up being interpreted like `a = a`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this:

```
if a = nil
```

should be:

```
if a == nil
```

A single `=` means assignment, and `a = nil` is assigning `nil` to `a` and evaluating to `nil` as a result, which is false. That's why the execution doesn't enter the `puts` part, whereas `==` means equality testing.

Other than that, what do you find strange in the code? It's normal behavior after all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you intended `a = nil` to be an assignment and knew it was not a comparison, it doesn't return whether or not it is successful.

It returns the value assigned, namely `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided is behaving as intended.

Perhaps you're confusing the assignment operator `=` with the comparison operator `==`. Try the last snipped of code like this:

```
if a == nil
  puts "should be nil"
end
=> nil
> a
=> "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "foo"­
# => "foo"
a = nil ? nil : a
# => "foo"
a
# => "foo"
```

To explain the above I would start with this - "Every thing in Ruby is an object except block;all object in Ruby is having a truth value,except `nil` and `false`." Thus in your above part of code `a = nil ? nil : a` expression will be evaluated as `a = a`. That's why 'foo'`has been returned as a value of`a`.

```
a = "bar"­ ? "bar"­ : a
# => "bar"
a
# => "bar"
```

As I just said except `nil` and `false` all object has truthy value,"bar" is always `true`. so the expression `a = "bar"­ ? "bar"­ : a` will be evaluated as `a = "bar"`.

```
if a = nil
  puts "should be nil"
end
=> nil
```

The same explanation goes to the `if a = nil` part as I explained above. So due to `false` control doesn't get into the `if` clause body,and returned `nil`.